# Effect on Fundamental Group after attaching 2-cell

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $Z$ is a topological space obtained from $X$ by attaching a 2-cell . Is the quotient space $Z/X $simply connected ?

I can't figure out this question . I thought first that it will be simply connected because after attaching 2-cell when I do quotient by the space $X$ , basically collapsing the space $X$ and attached a zero cell . So the quotient space contains a 2-cell with 0-cell and as 2- cell is nullhomotopic then space $Z/X$ is simply connected . Am I thinking wrong ? Please rectify if I am wrong . Does the Fundamental group of quotient space $Z/X $ depend on attaching map ?

Comment: The sentence "But another question comes in my mind that is there no effect on fundamental group of the quotient space /
 how do I give attaching map ?" is incomprehensible.

Comment: Sorry ! I have changed . Can you please check and give me some idea how should I proceed ?

Comment: It is clear now. You got a good hint in the posted answer (not a complete solution, of course). Try to follow it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The attaching map yields a homeomorphism $Z/X\cong D^2/S^1$.

Comment: sorry I can't get it . Characteristic map is the continuous extension of attaching map such that restriction on a cell is a homeomorphism . Here D^2/ S^1 is homeomorphic to S^2 . So ,what are you trying to say ? Is that Z/X is always simply connected ?

Comment: The map $D^2\to Z$ yields a map $D^2/S^1\to Z/X$. Show that it is a homeomorphism, you have figured out the rest.

Comment: @RUPAM Is something still unclear?

Comment: No , I got it .